# I'm trying to save in db multiple records with a form, but I have this error: Array to string conversion

Tags: database, laravel, controller

I tried to save records of multiple products in a table, in database, with a single form but, there is this error and I don't know hot to solve it.

Error: Array to string conversion

in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str

```
   $result .= (array_shift($replace) ?? $search).$segment;
```

Datatype of 'reference' and 'quantity' is string.

This is view:

```
<form action="{{route('carts.store')}}" method="post">
    @csrf

    @foreach(session('cart') as $id => $details)

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type=hidden class="form-control" name="reference[]" id="referenceNumber" value="{{ $details['reference'] }}">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type=hidden class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[]" value="{{$details['quantity']}}" id="productPrice">
        </div> 
                       
    @endforeach

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add products</button>

</form>
```

This is controller:

```php
    public function store(Request $request)
    {   
        $cart = new Cart;
        $data = [
            'reference' => $request->reference,
            'quantity' => $request->quantity
        ];
        $cart->fill($data);
        $cart->save();

        return view('riepilogo');
    }
```

When I click on button "add products" only the last records is saved in table

```php
class Cart extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'reference', 'pdv_code', 'quantity'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function product()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }    
}
```

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['ean', 'reference', 'product_price', 'pdv_code'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function detail() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Products_detail');
    }

    public function cart()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cart');
    }
}


> Blockquote
```

Migration:

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cart_product', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('cart_id');
            $table->foreign('cart_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('carts')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
            $table->foreign('product_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('products')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['cart_id', 'product_id']);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cart_product');
    }
```

Migration cart:

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->char('reference');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('carts');
    }
```

```
public function addToCart(Request $request, $id, $reference)
{
    $product = Product::find($id)->where('reference', $reference)->first();

    if(!$product) {

        abort(404);

    }
    
    $cart = session()->get('cart');

    // if cart is empty then this the first product
    if(!$cart) {

        $cart = [
                $id => [
                    "id" => $product->id,
                    "quantity" => 1,
                    "price" => $product->product_price,
                    "ean" => $product->ean,
                    "reference" => $product->reference
                ]
        ];
        //dd($cart);

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
    }

    // if cart not empty then check if this product exist then increment quantity
    if(isset($cart[$id])) {

        $cart[$id]['quantity']++;

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');

    }

    // if item not exist in cart then add to cart with quantity = 1
    $cart[$id] = [
        "id" => $product->id,
        "quantity" => 1,
        "price" => $product->product_price,
        "ean" => $product->ean,
        'reference' => $product->reference
    ];

    session()->put('cart', $cart);

    return back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
}
```

Comment: Where is *$result .= (array_shift($replace) ?? $search).$segment;* line coming from? What is the datatype of  **reference** & **quatity** columns on the Cart model. Where is the code for "add products" button

Comment: Sorry, I insert where is the error, datatype of reference and quantity  is string and I didn't translate button, is the button type submit at the and of the form

Comment: The data received when the form is submitted has both reference and quantity as array - and you are trying to assign to a column with string datatype

Comment: You are actually sending data for multiple carts from the form while you are creating only one new Cart in the controller - what you desire to do is not clear

Comment: In the cart I have multiple products, and I have to record a product in respective row in my table on database, but in the same cart.

Comment: Means inputs with name **reference** correspond to various products and input with **quantity** name correspond to the respective quantity - is that right? If so then the Cart model must have a relation with Product model and these data must be representing a record in the orders or cart_items table. Or do you plan to save everything in the carts table itself? Pls post the migration for the carts table

Comment: Yes is the answer at the first question.
I update the question and I insert model and migration

Comment: What are the properties/keys available in session('cart')? Where do you get the values for other fields for the cart - ` 'pdv_code'` and the reference and quantity on cart model what do they store? Are pdv_code, reference and quantity required or nullable fields on the cart

Comment: I added controller function where I get values for cart.
Only fields  quantity and reference are required

Comment: `$product = Product::find($id)->where('reference', $reference)->first();` - doesn't make sense. `id` is the primary key for products table so **Product::find($id)** id is unique and will find a record if it exists in the database corresponding to the given `$id`- doesn't need any where condition on it.

Comment: Yeah but the request is that I have to use parameters id and reference both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form should have a reference to the cart via the id for both input fields

```
<form action="{{route('carts.store')}}" method="post">
    @csrf

    @foreach(session('cart') as $id => $details)

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type=hidden class="form-control" name="{{ 'cart_items[' .$id . '][reference]' }}" id="referenceNumber" value="{{ $details['reference'] }}">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type=hidden class="form-control quantity" name="{{ 'cart_items[' . $id . '][quantity]' }}" value="{{$details['quantity']}}" id="productPrice">
        </div> 
                       
    @endforeach

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add products</button>

</form>
```

`$request->input('cart_items')` will give the array of all products added to the cart

And you need another model **CartItem** and table **cart_items** to store the line items for the cart where each line can have a product_id and quantity at the very least.

Or you can add the `quantity` and `price` column on the `cart_product` pivot table.

For the carts table: you can have columns: `total`, `tax` etc the product reference and quantity columns can't be on carts table its of no use  - a cart can have 3 products added for example to it [Tshirt: 1, Trouser: 2, Hoodie: 1] now which reference and which product's quantity will get stored in the carts table?

Instead there can be three records for cart_items table

Tshirt->id, quantity, cart_id

Trouser-id, quantity, cart_id

Hoodie->id, quantity, cart_id